# .htaccess redirect subfolder but don't show subfolder in address bar

Tags: .htaccess

I have a folder in my `public_html` directory named `landingPages` which obviously holds all our Landing Pages.

The problem is all the URLs on Google AdWords etc. are set to the public_html folder, for example:

```
http://www.example.com/landingPage1.php
```

Putting all the files in the new landingPages directory was done to clear up the public_html directory and seperate everything a bit but changing all the URLs is something we want to avoid.

I want that if you go to to `http://www.example.com/landingPage1.php` in the browser that it actually loads whats inside the `landingPages` folder so it calls `http://www.example.com/landingPages/landingPage1.php` in the background.

I have tried a few things but can't seem to find a catch all version to determine if whatever is requested in the browser is present in the landingPages folder and if so to re-direct or if this sort of catch all request is at all possible.

If not, I guess I would have to manually create rules for each file I want re-directed including any future created Landing Pages which is what I am trying to avoid here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this code in your .htaccess under the website root directory, this will check if the file exists in landingPages folder, if so, it will load the content of that file.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/landingPages/$1 -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /landingPages/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I have placed this one up from my public_html directory... Unfortunately it doesn't work though, I just get a 404 error.

Comment: Hi Amine... Appreciate the help... Not sure if I'm doing anything incorrectly here but still getting a 404 error when I try to access the page without the subfolder in the address bar.

Comment: Not in the .htaccess file above my public_html but there is on in the public_html folder which is a WordPress site, whether this has any affect I don't know.

Comment: ahh catch it , you have to place this code under your public_html folder not above it (public_html is the root directory of your website)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks, when you said put it in the root directory I thought you were meaning one up from the public folder... Put it in the public folder and all works perfectly now! Thanks